# Node.js update loop sequencing

Tags: javascript, node.js, game-physics

I've implemented a game loop in a node.js application that looks like this:

```
var physicsloop = gameloop.setGameLoop(function(dt) {
    var keys = Object.keys(worlds);
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
        updatePhysics(dt, worlds[keys[i]]);
    }
}, 1000 / 40);
```

It loops at approximately 40 times per second. I have a bunch of different instances that I want to update with some `updatePhysics` function that updates the physics state for a given delta time and instance (called a world in the code above).

Since there will be many different instances my concern is that `updatePhysics` might be called for a given instance before the previous `updatePhysics` has finished for that instance. Is this a concern with this kind of update loop? If so, how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: Are you aware how the event loop works? You may be able to achieve what you mean by using the `process.nextTick()` function to delay execution of the function until the current tick of the event loop has completed. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Queue` to restrict access at single point of time. Try this https://github.com/caolan/async#queue famous npm package.

Comment: Would I use an individual `Queue` for each instance and restrict the concurrency to 1 so none of the tasks can be processed in parallel _for that instance?_

Comment: I think using a single global queue is suffice. Check this video tutorial for better understanding http://nodetuts.com/series/asynchronous-programming/mastering-asynchronous-programming-08.html.